# Circular dependency c++ fails with forward decleration

Tags: c++, circular-dependency

I have two classes, MeassurementIteration and Meassurementset. A meassurementIteration has a vector of sets, and a set has a pointer to an iteration.

**Meassurementiteration**

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>
#include "MeassurementSetRepo.h"
#include "MeassurementSet.h"


    class MeassurementIteration
    {
    public:

        MeassurementIteration(const int id, const long start, const long end, const bool active)
            : id_(id)
            , start_(start)
            , end_(end)
            , active_(active)
        {}      

        MeassurementIteration();
        ~MeassurementIteration() = default;

        std::vector<MeassurementSet>& getMeasurementSet()
        {
            /** Magic **/
            return this->msSets_;
        }

    private:
        const int id_;
        const long start_;
        long end_;
        bool active_;
        MeassurementSetRepo mssetRepo;
        std::vector<MeassurementSet> msSets_;
    };
```

**Meassurementset**

```
#pragma once

#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include "MeassurementIterationRepo.h"

class MeassurementIteration;


    class MeassurementSet
    {

    public:
        MeassurementSet(const int id, const std::string & way, const int it_id) 
            : id_(id)
            , msWay_(way)
            , MeassurementIteration_Id_(it_id)
        {
            msit_ = nullptr;
        }

        ~MeassurementSet()
        {
            delete msit_;
        }

        MeassurementIteration& getMSIteration()
        {

            if (this->msit_ == nullptr)
            {
            /** Magic sets msit **/
            }
            return *msit_;  

        }

    private:
        int id_;
        const std::string msWay_;
        const int MeassurementIteration_Id_;
        MeassurementIterationRepo msitRepo_;
        MeassurementIteration * msit_;
    };
```

I cannot understand why I'm getting a circular dependency here. When I read other posts, it seems to be the way to do it. 
Can someone explain to me, what I'm doing wrong?

Update: The problem seems to be due to the use of the opposite class'es repository. To illustrate, see this figure.

How can I solve this dependency-hell?

[image: Dependencies]

Comment: Accurate titles of each header file would do wonders for clarity in this question, as would knowledge of what is in `"Meassurement.h"`, `"MeassurementSetRepo.h", and `"MeassurementIterationRepo.h".

Comment: When you forward-declare a class, you can declare a pointer if its type, but you cannot really work with it. So you have to move your inline functions which use `MeassurementIteration` to the .cpp file, where you can include both headers and both declarations are available.

Comment: It's most likely caused by contents of the files `#include`d in the files you posed.

Comment: btw, you didn't say what the error message is you are getting. It would help if you posted it as well.

Comment: Thank you. I tried making a dummy program with psedo-classes and made that work. The problem occured when I used the repo's. I've updated the question. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one important principle for you to learn, and that is interfacing.

The idea is that when I want to use one of your classes, all I want to know is *what* the class does. What I do not need to know is *how* it does it, aka the implementation details.

That is one of the reasons why C++ separates files into header files and source files. Header files should contain what it does, source files how it's done. One could even argue for a new format in which a header file contains nothing but public declarations (that is, without private member variables, private helper methods etc.).

Using this would help your cause. I don't see any problematic line in particular at first glance, but it might be that IterationRepo includes Iteration includes Set includes IterationRepo.

How having interfaces would help you: In headers, declare only, do not implement anything (some do that with one-liners, but I recommend not doing that either). Forward-declare only. Include in source files. You can't have a circular dependency this way.

(The rule is broken for member variable types of course - if A has a member variable that is B, it needs to know what B is in order to know it's size, therefore it needs to include it in the header.)